# Is there an analytical solution to this differential equation : $y''+\alpha yy'+\beta y'+\gamma y^{3}=0?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this set of differential equations:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dD(t)}{dt}&=-\frac{k}{2}D(t)^2-KI(t)D(t)\\
\frac{dI(t)}{dt}&=\frac{k}{2}D(t)^2\\
\frac{dF(t)}{dt}&=KI(t)D(t)
\end{align*}

After some calculations, I obtained a differential equation of the form :
$$D''(t)+\alpha D(t)D'(t)+\beta D'(t)+\gamma D(t)^{3}=0$$

I wonder if an analytical solution exists ? I found a solution for $$D''(t)+\alpha D(t) D'(t)+\gamma D(t)^3=0$$
but the term $\beta D'(t)$ is giving me trouble.

Perhaps there exists also a simpler way to solve this set of differential equations?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Moo. They are functions of k and K but still constants.

Comment: I believe this is a SIR model? I can't find this specific version with the $D(t)^2$, where did you get it?

Comment: You've got the particular solution $D(t),\ I(t),\ F(t)$ ~ $1/t$.

Comment: Not saying that this does not have a solution but I have spent a Phd + years after completing trying to solve $y'' + (y-c)y' + ay + bky^2 = 0$ and know it rather well plus created perturbative solutions for the limit cycle for my equation - now for you equation you will have similar issue - integrable versions are $\beta = 0$ and source $aD$. Basically if $\beta \new 0$ you will struggle to find solutions. I will probably write up my equation as an open problem .. one day when I have given up completely.

Comment: I cannot arrive at your ODE for $D(t)$, dividing the first equation by $D$  and taking a derivative I get 
\begin{align}
D''-\frac{(D')^2}{D}+\frac{k}{2}DD'+\frac{kK}{2}D^3=0.
\end{align}
May seem a bit messier but this also has the particular solution ~$1/t$, as opposed to the ODE you have come across, which leads me to believe a concise solution is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your first two ODE's
\begin{align}
D'=-\frac{k}{2}D^2-KID,\ \ \ \ \
I'=\frac{k}{2}D^2,
\end{align}
divide the first by $D$ and take a derivative,
\begin{align}
\frac{D''}{D}-&\left(\frac{D'}{D}\right)^2+\frac{k}{2}D'+KI'=0,\\
\frac{D''}{D}-&\left(\frac{D'}{D}\right)^2+\frac{k}{2}D'+\frac{kK}{2}D^2=0.
\end{align}
Let
\begin{align}
D'=\frac{1}{p},\ \ \ \ \ 
D''=-\frac{1}{p^3}\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dD},
\end{align}
so that the ODE becomes
\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{Dp^3}\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dD}-\frac{1}{(pD)^2}+\frac{k}{2p}+\frac{kK}{2}D^2=0.
\end{align}
Now substitute
\begin{align}
p=\frac{1}{Du},\ \ \ \ \ 
\frac{\mathrm dp}{\mathrm dD}=-\frac{1}{D^2u}-\frac{1}{Du^2}\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dD},
\end{align}
so then \begin{align}
u\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dD}+\frac{k}{2}u+\frac{kK}{2}D=0.
\end{align}
The final substitution of $D=-2\xi/k$ brings the equation to
\begin{align}
u\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm d\xi}=u+\frac{2K}{k}\xi.
\end{align}
The solution to this is presented in the book *Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations* by Polyanin & Zaitsev, (I'm unsure how this was derived), in parametric form
\begin{align}
\xi=c_1 \exp\left(-\int \frac{\tau \mathrm d\tau}{\tau^2-\tau-2K/k}\right), \ \ \ \ \ u=\tau\xi,
\end{align}
Where $c_1$ is the constant of integration. After undoing the substitutions you'll get that
\begin{align}
D=-\frac{2c_1}{k}\exp\left(-\int \frac{\tau \mathrm d\tau}{\tau^2-\tau-2K/k}\right), \ \ \ \ \ \tau=-\frac{2}{k}\frac{D'}{D^2}.
\end{align}
I believe the author intentionally left the integral as is, since I don't think you can find $\tau(D)$ analytically (but the form in the book is a bit more general, a constant tacked onto the Abel equation, which only slightly complicates the parametric solution), here is the algebraic equation to solve:
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{kD}{2c_1}\right)^2(k\tau^2-k\tau-2K)\left(\frac{2k\tau-\sqrt{k(8K+k)}-k}{2k\tau+\sqrt{k(8K+k)}-k}\right)^{\frac{k}{\sqrt{k(8K+k)}}}=\tau^2,
\end{align}
which I won't be typing into Wolfram Alpha. If you can solve this, you'd be able to separate and integrate to find $t(D)$ and possibly $D(t)$:
\begin{align}
\int \frac{\mathrm dD}{\tau(D)D^2}=c_2-\frac{k}{2}t.
\end{align}
I believe you could do this numerically, but at that point you could just numerically solve the original system.

----Edit----

Substituting the second ODE into the first yields the equation
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{K}\frac{I''}{I}+\left(\frac{k}{2K^2}-\frac{1}{K}\right)\left(\frac{I'}{I}\right)^2+I'=0.
\end{align}
Substituting $I'=\Lambda\rightarrow I''=\Lambda\mathrm d\Lambda/\mathrm dI$, yields
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d\Lambda}{\mathrm dI}+\left(\frac{k}{2K}-1\right)\frac{\Lambda}{I}+I=0. \tag{$\dagger$}
\end{align}
Multiplying by the integrating factor $I^{k/2K-1}$ gives
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dI}\left(I^{k/2K-1}\Lambda\right)+I^{k/2K}=0\\
I^{k/2K-1}\Lambda+\frac{2K}{k+2K}I^{k/2K+1}=c_1\\
\Lambda=I'=c_1I^{1-k/2K}-\frac{2K}{k+2K}I^2\\
\int \left(c_1I^{1-k/2K}-\frac{2K}{k+2K}I^2\right)^{-1}\mathrm dI=t+c_2.
\end{align}
The solution to this integral is a [Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function),
\begin{align}
\frac{I^{2-k/2K}}{c_1}\ _2F_1\left(1, \frac{k-4K}{k-6K};\frac{2k-10K}{k-6K};\frac{2K}{c_1(k+2K)}I^{3-k/2K}\right)=t+c_2,
\end{align}
which you can only find the inverse of numerically. For $k$ being integer multiples of $K$ the integral is nicer (simpler non-elementary functions), but I could only find one case where the result was invertible via elementary function, $k=2K$, which yields the solution
\begin{align}
   I(t)=c_1\tanh\left[\frac{c_1}{2}t+c_2\right].
\end{align}
But even then, the solution for $D(t)$ still requires a Hypergeometric function, and I can't imagine you'd be able to analytically find $F(t)$.

I apologize for the wall of math. All of this was to say it's not worth the effort! I believe it's time to turn to numerical methods.

Comment: $D' = 1/p(D)$ Is this justified? There is no such function if $D$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I'm not entirely sure. I believe this is an SIR model, in which case $D$ is probably deaths, I'd reason that $D$ would be monotonic.

Comment: @Eli. Thanks a lot. First, I have done a mistake in my ODE for D(t). Then, It is not a SIR model. D=Departure, I=Intermediate, F=Final. It is a chemistry model. If I may, could you,please, explain me how you calculate the algebraic equation to solve ?

Comment: @Stef1611 If it is solvable you'd likely use an computer algebraic system (like Wolfram Alpha) to do so. After I made the post I tried $I(t)$ and it's a bit more straight-forward, I'll edit my post to show it.